# Parse Number from string with regex

Tags: regex, numbers, integer, trailing

I have thousands of article descriptions containing numbers.

they look like:

ca.2760h3x1000.5DIN345x1500e34

the resulting numbers should be:

1. 2760
2. 1000.5
3. 1500

- h3 or 3 shall not be a result of the parsing, since h3 is a tolerance only
- same for e34
- DIN345 is a norm an needs to be excluded (every number with a trailing DIN or BN)

My current REGEX is:

- [^hHeE]([-+]?([0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+))

This solves everything BUT the norm. How can I get this "DIN" and "BN" treated the same way as a single character ?

Thanx, TomE

Comment: which language? regex is not the same among different languages

Comment: @Avinash I don't think that edit came out quite right. OP: Lookarounds are probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Michelle reverted back..

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/20 ?

Comment: Are all the strings in that format? `ca.####h3x####.#DINx####e34`? If not can you show us some of the other formats and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regular expression:

```
(?<=x)[+-]?0*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?|[+-]?0*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?=h|e)
```

It looks like every number in your testcase you want to match exept the first number is starting with x.

This is what the first part of the regex matches. `(?<=x)[+-]?0*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?`

The second part of the regex matches the number until h or e. `[+-]?0*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?=h|e)`

The two parts `[+-]?0*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?` in the regex is to match the number.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that the numbers are always going to be **four digits long**, you can use the regex:

```
    (\d{4}\.\d+|\d{4})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/21)

Depending on the language you might need to replace `\d` with `[0-9]`.